# Show product prices in Prestashop Wishlist Module

Tags: prestashop

Currently the wishlist module in my Prestashop store only displays the product image and title. There are two wishlist views, the customer account view and the shared link view. I would like to display the price in both of these views. I've tried adding

```
$price = Product::getPriceStatic($productid);
```

to different parts of managewishlist.php and adding

```
<span id="our_price_display">{convertPrice price=$productPrice}</span>
```

to the managewishlist tpl file but nothing shows up. I'm running version 1.5.6.2.

EDIT: I also tried adding

```
{if !$priceDisplay || $priceDisplay == 2}       
{assign var='productPrice' value=$product->getPrice(true, $smarty.const.NULL, $priceDisplayPrecision)}
{assign var='productPriceWithoutReduction' value=$product->getPriceWithoutReduct(false, $smarty.const.NULL)}
{elseif $priceDisplay == 1}
{assign var='productPrice' value=$product->getPrice(false, $smarty.const.NULL, $priceDisplayPrecision)}
{assign var='productPriceWithoutReduction' value=$product->getPriceWithoutReduct(true, $smarty.const.NULL)}
{/if}
```

to managewishlist.tpl but it made the wishlist disappear

Comment: Please provide more details, what version of prestashop? what have you tried? where do you want to add the price? Questions like "please do this for me" tend to quickly get deleted...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just added those details. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you add `productPrice` to the smarty variables (with `$this->context->smarty->assign`)?

Comment: I had not done that but I just found something similar in product tpl I tried adding but it made the whole wishlist disappear. I added what I tried to my edit above

Comment: Any help you can give is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the actual files you need to edit but this should be right for PS 1.5.x

in blockwishlist/view.php add the commented line:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($products); ++$i)
    {
        $obj = new Product($products[$i]['id_product'], false, $context->language->id);
        if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($obj))
            continue;
        else
        {
            if ($products[$i]['id_product_attribute'] != 0 && isset($combination_imgs[$products[$i]['id_product_attribute']][0]))
            {
                $combination_imgs = $obj->getCombinationImages($context->language->id);
                $products[$i]['cover'] = $obj->id.'-'.$combination_imgs[$products[$i]['id_product_attribute']][0]['id_image'];
            }
            else
            {
                $images = $obj->getImages($context->language->id);
                foreach ($images AS $k => $image)
                {
                    if ($image['cover'])
                    {
                        $products[$i]['cover'] = $obj->id.'-'.$image['id_image'];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!isset($products[$i]['cover']))
                    $products[$i]['cover'] = $context->language->iso_code.'-default';
            }
            // ADD THIS LINE!
            $products[$i]['price'] = Product::getPriceStatic($obj->id);
        }
    }
```

then in `view.tpl` (not sure if PS 1.5.x uses the /templates/view/ dir or not try both) you can just use `{convertPrice price=$product.price}` wherever you need.

Haven't actually tested this but it should give you a good starting point at least.

**EDIT** Also please be aware that that editing module files directly is not recommended. However, since there is no option to override modules in PS 1.5.x your only options are:

a) editing module directly - **meaning it will break if / when you update said module**

b) copying the module and renaming it - which is messy but imho preferable to the downside of *a)*

Comment: I really appreciate the help, I am going to keep working at it. My file is different so I must be not placing it right.